# Building solution in TFS server cannot find assemblies from external NuGet source

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

I am unable to successfully build the solution on the TFS server. Although, it looks like all of my NuGet packages restored, I keep getting the error *Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyAssembly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*. FYI this successfully builds on my local environment.

### Build Steps

Here is what I have provided for the build steps:

#### NuGet Restore

These are the inputs I have provided while everything else uses the default value:

- **Path to solution or packages.config:** $/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp.sln
- **Path to NuGet.config:** $/MyApp/MyApp/NuGet.Config
- **Installation type:** Restore

Inside my NuGet.Config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="My Packages" value="\\server\Nuget Packages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

When this build step runs, it succeeds and says:

> All packages listed in packages.config are already installed

#### Build Solution

These are the inputs I have provided while everything else uses the default value:

- **Solution**: $/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp.sln

When this build step runs, I get errors similar to:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyAssembly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

### Folder Structure

Here is the folder structure of the solution and the package.configs

- MyApp

  - MyApp.Core

    - package.config
  - MyApp.Web

    - package.config
  - NuGet.Config
  - MyApp.sln

Any suggestions would be helpful and please let me know if additional information needs to be provided. Thanks!

Comment: This is tagged with both `tfs` and `azure-devops`. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, it is for tfs, I removed the tag for azure-devops

Comment: Hey Ron, the missing DLL is it from nuget.org or from you local nuget server? Can you login on the build server and go to the agent work path and look in source folder \packages directory and see if your package is actually there?  Does this package have an install.ps1 as part of it, if it does it won't run on the restore step.

Answer (score 0):

> Building solution in TFS server cannot find assemblies from external NuGet source

NuGet will check the packages directory for the solution when it restores.

It checks that this packages directory contains the .nupkg and manifest file for the NuGet package and if so it believes the NuGet package is already installed.

**So**, to resolve the issue, you should make sure you are not add the `\packages` folder in to source control. If yes, please try to remove it out of source control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution but the packages folder is not added to the source control

Comment: @ron2019, Sorry, that answer not help you. It seems you are using the nuget restore task with version `0.*`, you can try to use the version `2.0*`, if it still not help you. Please share you build definition about nuget restore task and the log in your question.